# apache https to http Nginx

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, proxy, transparent

My configuration is as follows - 1 unix server with two http servers running at the same time:

1. apache server on ports 80 and 443
2. Nginx server on port 8200   (www.myserver.com:8200)

The problem is that when I log in to Nginx site I need to authorize there. Doing this over internet with no SSL is not wise... I would like to connect to my apache server with SSL, be transparently redirected to another site and authorize still having encrpyted connection.

Nginx works via http so no ssl there... I would like to have url
**https://www.myserver.com/duplicati** to be proxied to **http://www.myserver.com:8200**

Effectively I want to have:

1. encrypted connection from the web client to www.myserver.com
2. proxy connection from https://www.myserver.com/duplicati to http://www.myserver.com:8200 (unencrypted), but limited to 1 physical machine which I don't care much about encryption (or actually lack of it)

What I did was the following

What I did was the following Apache config:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /duplicati/ http://127.0.0.1:8200/ngax/
ProxyPassReverse /duplicati/ http://127.0.0.1:8200/ngax/
<Location /duplicati/>
  ProxyPassReverse /
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all     
</Location>
Header edit Location ^http://127.0.0.1:8200/ngax/ https://127.0.0.1:8200/ngax/
```

still no luck with that config....

It looks like a simple thing to do but after 5h of struggle I need to send my very first post to Stackoverflow community ;-)

Could you kindly help me with it?

Comment: You should share exactly what you need help with. You said you spent 5 hours on this already – maybe share what you've tried. It's really not clear what you specifically want advice on.

Comment: why are you using apache as a proxy in front of nginx ?

Comment: @OSAMAH - correct  - apache is a frontend to nginx

Comment: @AdamKaplan. Ok sorry for being not so specific.